# If A has r independent columns and B has r independent rows, AB is invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am learning the MIT ocw 18.06 Linear Algebra, and there is a problem in problem set 5 as below:

Problem 34. If A has r independent columns and B has r independent rows, AB
is invertible.
Proof: When A is m by r with independent columns, we know that $A^TA$ is invertible.
If B is r by n with independent rows, show that $BB^T$ is invertible. (Take A = $B^T$ .)
Now show that AB has rank r.

But I think BA is invertible other than AB, so this problem makes me confused.
Am I understanding something wrong here? Thanks a lot.

Comment: OK, so now you've added more information. This is sloppy writing to include hypotheses about $A$ and $B$ in the proof. So, yes, if $A$ is $m\times r$ and $B$ is $r\times n$ and each has rank $r$, then $AB$ has rank $r$. What are the solutions of $(AB)x=0$? (By the way, $BA$ doesn't even make sense.)

Comment: The solutions are n-r dimensional subspace in $R^n$, am I right?

Comment: What shape does $AB$ have?

Comment: Yes, you're right. $AB$ is $m\times n$. What is the dimension of the solution space to $Bx=0$? Why are the only solutions of $(AB)x = 0$ the solutions of $Bx=0$? So if you get the solution space $(n-r)$-dimensional, that tells you, then, that $AB$ has rank $r$. :)

Comment: AB is a m by n matrix, may not be a square matrix. Further more, the solutions of (AB)x=0 are n-r dimensional subspace in $R^n$, the nullspace contains not only the zero vector when n isn't r, so AB may not be invertible. AB is invertible only if r=n=m. Have I got the point?

Comment: You don't want $AB$ invertible. It's not even square!! You want its rank to be $r$. So you need to show the solutions of $(AB)x=0$ form an $(n-r)$-dimensional subspace. You haven't made that argument, have you? It takes two steps.

Comment: Because of the independent columns, the only solution of Ax=0 is the zero vector, so the only solutions of (AB)x=0 or A(Bx)=0 are the solutions of Bx=0 which form an (n−r)-dimensional subspace. Sorry that I was not able to reply in time because I spend some time thinking about your questions. Thank you very much!

Comment: OK, good, Thomas. :) Keep going!!